# Unity ADS не работает на устройстве

Tags: unity3d, ads

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое может получиться.
Проект с *Unity ADS*, в тестовом режиме, работал прекрасно, тестовая реклама (`rewardedVideo`) воспроизводилась на устройствах и на PC тоже все ок.
После аварии с проектом(изменил случайно версию проекта на более позднюю, все сломалось) пришлось восстанавливать проект из резервной копии.
Теперь каким то образом на PC все норм, `Advertisement.IsReady(myPlacementId) = true`, кнопка рекламы активна.
На устройствах(проверил на двух телефонах) не активна, `Advertisement.IsReady(myPlacementId) = false`.
Не могу найти причину...

Answer (score 0):

В общем обновил Unity Monetization и все заработало. Так и не понял прикола